# Trouble finding input text in a form Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm creating a simple web app that tests a user's typing speed.  I have a start button in the html which starts a timer, an input text field for the user to type something, and a stop button that stops the time, extracts what the user typed, and records results.

Eventually, I want to be able to load up a sample text for the user to type to record both speed and accuracy.  But I cannot seem to get what the user types into the form input field.

Here is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

test_text = "Hello. The year is 2024."
speed = 0
accuracy = 0
user_text = " "
@app.route('/', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    global t0, speed, accuracy, user_text
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['button'] == 'Start_Button':
            t0 = time.time()
        elif request.form['button'] == 'Stop_Button':
            t = time.time() - t0
            user_text = request.form.get('users_text')
            word_count = len(user_text.split(" "))
            if word_count > 0:
                speed = word_count / t
                correct_chars = 0
                for i in range(len(user_text)):
                    if test_text[i] == user_text[i]:
                        correct_chars += 1

                accuracy = 100 * (correct_chars/len(user_text))
            
            

    return render_template('index.html', speed=speed, accuracy=accuracy)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is the associated HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Test Out Your Typing Speed</h1>

       <div class="box">
       <h3 id="instructions">Press the Start Button and then type in the field below.  Then, press the Stop Button.
       </h3>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
        <form method="post" action="/">
            <button type="submit" id="Start_Button" name="button" value="Start_Button">Start</button>
       </form>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
       <form method="post">
            <input type="text" id="user_type_box" name="users_text" placeholder="Type here">
       </form>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
        <form method="post" action="/">
            <button type="submit" id="Stop_Button" name="button" value="Stop_Button">Stop</button>
       </form>
       </div>

       <h3>Typing Speed: {{speed}}</h3>
       <h3>Accuracy: {{accuracy}}</h3>
    
</html>
```

I looked online at geeks for geeks article which said to use request.form.get method for input form field.  I can't get it to work right.  The flask error message I get is that python cannot execute split on variable of type NoneType, which tells me that the python code is not assigning anything to variable to store the user text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on a submit button, it only sends the input fields that are in the same form. By default these are the fields that are within the same `<form>` and `</form>`, although other inputs can be associated with the form using the `form="formID"` attribute.

Since you have the text input in a different form from the stop button, the input text isn't submitted when you click the button. Wrap the form around both inputs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test Out Your Typing Speed</h1>

  <div class="box">
    <h3 id="instructions">Press the Start Button and then type in the field below. Then, press the Stop Button.
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <form method="post" action="/">
      <button type="submit" id="Start_Button" name="button" value="Start_Button">Start</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <form method="post" action="/">
    <div class="box">
      <input type="text" id="user_type_box" name="users_text" placeholder="Type here">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <button type="submit" id="Stop_Button" name="button" value="Stop_Button">Stop</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <h3>Typing Speed: {{speed}}</h3>
  <h3>Accuracy: {{accuracy}}</h3>

</html>
```

Comment: That did the trick!!  That you so much, sir.